# Defer function execution order

Tags: go

I am learning the golang source code and get stuck in the defer function execution order.
I have two files: one defines the behavior of an endpoint and another one for the test. I remove some code unrelated to my question to reduce the lines to read.
The endpoint definition file

```
// Endpoint is the fundamental building block of servers and clients.
// It represents a single RPC method.
type Endpoint func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (response interface{}, err error)

// Middleware is a chainable behavior modifier for endpoints.
type Middleware func(Endpoint) Endpoint

// Chain is a helper function for composing middlewares. Requests will
// traverse them in the order they're declared. That is, the first middleware
// is treated as the outermost middleware.
func Chain(outer Middleware, others ...Middleware) Middleware {
    return func(next Endpoint) Endpoint {
        for i := len(others) - 1; i >= 0; i-- { // reverse
            next = others[i](next)
        }
        return outer(next)
    }
}
```

The test file contains the printed steps.

```
func ExampleChain() {
    e := endpoint.Chain(
        annotate("first"),
        annotate("second"),
        annotate("third"),
    )(myEndpoint)

    if _, err := e(ctx, req); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Output:
    // first pre
    // second pre
    // third pre
    // my endpoint!
    // third post
    // second post
    // first post
}

var (
    ctx = context.Background()
    req = struct{}{}
)

func annotate(s string) endpoint.Middleware {
    return func(next endpoint.Endpoint) endpoint.Endpoint {
        return func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            fmt.Println(s, "pre")
            defer fmt.Println(s, "post")
            return next(ctx, request)
        }
    }
}

func myEndpoint(context.Context, interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    fmt.Println("my endpoint!")
    return struct{}{}, nil
}
```

To my understanding, the three `annotate` methods should be executed first, followed by the `endpoint.Chain` method and `myEndpoint` should be executed in the end. Also since the `pre` is printed first and when the funtion returns "post" should follow according to the `defer` explanation in the go doc:
`A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is panicking.`

So what I expect to see is

```
    // Output:
    // first pre
    // first post
    // second pre
    // second post
    // third pre
    // third post
    // my endpoint!
```

In short, my questions are:

1. why `first pre` is not followed by `first post`, same as `second` `third`.
2. the order of `post`s is reversed. the `endpoint.Chain` reverse the execution of a list of `annotate` returned values but `annotate` methods are evaluated first right? Not to say, the `pre`s get printed which means the inner funtions are executed first

Comment: How could the outer function return before the inner one is even called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deferred function runs as the last thing in the function, after the return statement, so the `annotate` function will first run `next`, and only after that returns the deferred function will run. Based on your code, the order it should print is:

```
first pre
second pre
third pre
my endpoint
third post
second post
first post
```

Comment: look like this does not answer my first question. From the comments posted, it can only explain why `post` should happen after `pre` but does not explain why `first` and `second` interleave?

Comment: It is because deferred functions run *after* `next` is called and it returned.  So, first pre, then second, pre, etc. and first post will only print after second returns.

Comment: shouldn't the first `next` call return immediately? I didn't see it has dependency on the second one

Comment: Based on your constructs, first calls second, second calls third, and then third calls the endpoint. Then endpoint returns, then third, then second, and then first.

Comment: maybe a silly question, can you point me the line of code which has the logic you mentioned? The annotate method just return the functions and does not run any line of the code. The `Chain` method executes the three function in the reverse order

Comment: `endpoint.Chain` calls annotate, which returns a middleware function. `Chain` calls middleware functions to setup a chain of calls so that every middleware is called with the next one in chain. This chain is returned as a middleware, and when called, it first calls the chain, and then the endpoint function.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is your example turned into something that runs on the Go playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/_d1CwdFTdbZ)

Note that if you call `defer` *more than once* in a given function, each deferred call runs in LIFO order.  So if you want to use `defer` to make sure your `post` gets called first, and *then* the `next` operates, consider replacing:

```
defer fmt.Println(s, "post")
next(ctx, request)
```

with:

```
defer next(ctx, request)
defer fmt.Println(s, "post)
```

Of course, in your case you want to *return what `next` returns*, which creates a small problem.  To work around this in real cases you need a small function and some named return values:

```
defer func() { i, e = next(ctx, request) }()
```

where `i` and `e` are the named return values.

[Here is that same code turned into a new example in which the deferred calls occur in the desired order.](https://play.golang.org/p/_JRZBNU0PZF)  In this case, the example is rather silly, as nothing panics and there are no "dangerous steps" in between, so all we really need is to do the two `fmt.Println` calls sequentially, without using `defer`.  But if we *could* panic *between* the `fmt.Println(s, "pre")` and the post section, then this might make sense.